# On button click put all elements src to array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have many divs with id="imgLinks"

```
<div><img  id="imgLinks" u=image src="../../../../images/1.jpg" /></div>
<div><img  id="imgLinks" u=image src="../../../../images/3.jpg" /></div>
<div><img  id="imgLinks" u=image src="../../../../images/5.jpg" /></div>
```

I need on button click put all src to array

```
$(document).on('click', '#navigation #Download', function() {
    var imgLinks = [];
    $("#imgLinks").each(function() {
        var name = $(this).attr("src");
        imgLinks.push(name);
    });
});
```

But this code put only first source, how to put all of them?

Comment: Move `var imgLinks = []` outside of the `click` handler. You're redefining it every time you click an image

Comment: ids should be unique per element in a single page. invalid markup. change to `class='imgLinks'` instead and change your selector to class selector then.

Comment: If you have no control over the HTML, you could use `$("[id='imgLinks']")` instead, but I highly suggest you follow what @Jai said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change `id` attribute to `class` because same ids in a single page not allowed/ produces invalid markup.

```
$(document).on('click', '#navigation #Download', function() {
    var imgLinks = $(".imgLinks").map(function() {
            return $(this).attr("src");
        }).get();
    console.log(imgLinks); // [array]
});
```

`.map().get()` lets you create an array while returning the src of every `.imgLink` in each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Even though having same `ID` for different elements seems to make any difference, having Unique IDs are the standard way. You can either change the `ID` to `class` and then select using the class name or utilize the `attribute` you have used

```
$(document).on('click', '#navigation #Download', function() {
    var imgLinks = [];
    $('img[u=image]').each(function() {
        var name = $(this).attr("src");
        imgLinks.push(name);
    });
});
```

**Edit to improve answer based on accepted answer.**

```
$(document).on('click', '#navigation #Download', function() {
    var imgLinks = $('img[u=image]').map(function() {
            return $(this).attr("src");
        }).get();
});
```